# String checking - large set of patterns - java

Tags: java, regex, performance

I need to check for a input string, that can match against 1 or more patterns in Java..

I tried with if - else checking of the matching values..but i have more than 100+ checks to 
do and such a if-else is not good way to do it either..

Also looping through each string and checking the input string could be intensive.

Is there a simple way and whose performance is good as well.

Sample values are below(there are almost 100+ such pattern)

If I give the input as IP|VAR|D00|PB|TM|AB , i should get the 3 patterns matching...
And i need to pick the values of each of the pattern ...

```
IP|VAR|**                         - IPVAR
IP|VAR|D00|*                      - IPVARD00
IP|VAR|D00|PB|*                     - IPVARE 
IP|ANBT|D00|*                     - IPVARAD
IK|**|ServiceApp or IK|**|Ser|    - IKSER
```

Comment: Could you store the patterns in an external file, read it, and loop over the patterns for checking the input against it?

Comment: What does it mean "to pick a value of each of the pattern"? Please explain why do you need the pattern matching. I mean lets's say you string matches 3 pattern of 100. So what? What are you doing as a result of the match?

Comment: I need to retrieve the value corresponding to the pattern as key and use it for further logic processing.. ex:IPVAR,IPVARD00,IPVARE

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

File: `patterns`

```
tucky*
Fried
Chi*
Unix
Apple
Nikon
```

File: `words`

```
Kentucky Fried Chicken
Nikon
```

Then searching like this:

```
grep -f patterns words
Kentucky Fried Chicken
Nikon
```

Or with `-o`

```
grep -o -f patterns words
tucky
Fried
Chi
Nikon
```

Comment: Hi Mark, the patterns could be Kentucky Fried Chicken|**| (** could be  any text)

Comment: Yeah Mark, similar to this grep -o -f patterns words
                                                                        But my implementation is in jAva

Answer (score 0):

Loop is the way to go: if you really need to check that many patterns, there isn't much you can do but trying them in a loop.

If all your patterns start in two fixed letters, there is a simple optimization to be applied here: group all patterns by the first two letters, then check the first two letters of the incoming strings, and pick the pattern group based on it. For example, if the first two letters of a string are `'I'` and `'P'`, then you should loop only the patterns that start in `"IP|"`, and skip the remaining patterns.

One way to organize your patterns in groups by the first two characters is to use a `Map`:

```
Map<String,List<MyPattern>> patterns = ...
```

Now you can do this:

```
List<MyPattern> applicablePatterns = patterns.get(inputString.substring(0, 2));
for (MyPattern p : applicablePatterns) {
    // This loop is much shorter
}
```